# New page is not relacing the existing parent page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a html page and on GO button i have write redirecting code

```
window.location.replace(url);
```

I put this page in iframe and on click on GO button result page should open in the existing page replacing the url of the browser but it is opning in iframe only...
I tried
`<base target="_parent" />` also but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.top.location.href` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your result page needs to break out of the iframe:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_breakout